# Select elements not child of specific selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select all hyperlinks inside a div which are not child of a div with "test" class. I thought that `$("a", $("div").not(".test"))` would work, but if I put another div inside the div with class "test" my selection doesn't works.
In the following example I should select only the links 4, 5 and 6, what I need to achieve this task?

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var notAds = $("a", $("div").not(".test"));
console.log(links.length);
console.log(notAds.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="test1.html">test 1 link</a>
      <a href="test2.html">test 2 link</a>
      <a href="test3.html">test 3 link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="test4.html">test 4 link</a>
  <a href="test5.html">test 5 link</a>
  <a href="test6.html">test 6 link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `not` method in order to find elements that doesn't have as parent the `div` with `test` class.

```
var notAds = $("a").not($('.test').find('a'));
```

> `not` method remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var notAds = $("a").not($('.test').find('a'));
console.log("Length: " + notAds.length);
$(notAds).map(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="test1.html">test 1 link</a>
      <a href="test2.html">test 2 link</a>
      <a href="test3.html">test 3 link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="test4.html">test 4 link</a>
  <a href="test5.html">test 5 link</a>
  <a href="test6.html">test 6 link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using the `.not()` method, not the selector.